# command line mysql client not opening ubuntu 12.10

Tags: mysql, lamp

**i am unable to start mysql client in terminal  i use the following command to stat mysql client**

> sudo mysql

and got the following error

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

i use this command to start my server

> sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

please tell what i am doing wrong .

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on serverfault?

Comment: -1: This question should really be on serverfault.

Comment: @Oshawott so flag it as such.

Comment: @Oshawott and remove down vote, it's a perfectly reasonable question... Except he got the server wrong.

Comment: My down vote is locked. :(

Comment: My bad luck :(:(:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1`.

For some reason mysql from XAMPP doesn't bind socket.

Comment: THX Brother its just worked for me 

mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p xxxxx

Comment: XAMPP has no root password on mysql by default, so -p operator not needed unless you've run XAMPP security.

Comment: I was looking for this answer many days. Thank a lot.